# Angular 5 variable is not defined

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to submit a form in Angular 5. My motive is to catch the form values and also define some static values in the variables.

Below is the form snippet.

```html
<main class="container my-3 my-md-5">
 <form id="paymentForm" method="POST" (ngSubmit)="sendPaymentDataToAnet()" #payFrm="ngForm">
     <input type="text" maxlength="16" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber" placeholder="cardNumber" ngModel [(ngModel)]="cardNumber"/> <br><br>
     <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="expMonth" id="expMonth" placeholder="expMonth"/> <br><br>
     <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="expYear" id="expYear" placeholder="expYear"/> <br><br>
     <input type="text" maxlength="3" name="cardCode" id="cardCode" placeholder="cardCode"/> <br><br>
     <input type="hidden" name="dataValue" id="dataValue" />
     <input type="hidden" name="dataDescriptor" id="dataDescriptor" />
     <button type="submit" >Pay</button>
 </form>
</main>
```

Now in the name.component.ts, I've defined the variable as:

```
export class PAYComponent implements OnInit {
    authData: any;
    // bla bla
```

This is the form submission code:

```
sendPaymentDataToAnet(form: NgForm) { 
authData.clientKey = "XXX2";
}
```

However, when submitting the form, I see below error in my console:

```
    ReferenceError: authData is not defined
        at PAYComponent.push../src/app/features/pay/pay.component.ts.PAYComponent.sendPaymentDataToAnet
...
```

In Javascript, the authData can be declared as : `var authData = {};`
As per the Angular guidance I declared the variable as `authData: any;`

What was my fault?

Comment: Angular is javascript too. Just do `authData: any = {};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot about `this`.

```
sendPaymentDataToAnet(form: NgForm) { 
  this.authData.clientKey = "XXX2";
}
```